# How can I mount a password-protected Windows share in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5?

Tags: linux, windows, redhat

How can I mount a password-protected Windows share in Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5?

Answer (score 1):

**this is untested:**

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/ntserver
# mount -t cifs //ntserver/download -o username=shareuser,password=sharePassword /mnt/ntserver
```

...where you replace 'shareuser' and 'sharepassword' with the corresponding data from a account on your windows machine. start with a simple password you don't have to escape in the above commandline.